# Suzuki Sporadic Group on Sage

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, computational-mathematics, sagemath

I need to call the Suzuki Sporadic group in Sage. I found the following command in the documentation.

```
G = groups.permutation.SuzukiSporadic()
```

This gives me a GAPError so I tried similar commands, but they all give me an error.

Comment: In GAP, you can create it using `SimpleGroup("Suz");` so however this translates into Sage syntax should do.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the optional `gap_packages` Sage package. If you look at the documentation for `groups.permutation.SuzukiSporadic()`, you should see:

```
sage: groups.permutation.SuzukiSporadic?
Init signature: groups.permutation.SuzukiSporadic()
Docstring:     
   Suzuki Sporadic Group

   EXAMPLES:

      sage: G = groups.permutation.SuzukiSporadic(); G # optional - gap_packages internet
      Sporadic Suzuki group acting on 1782 points
```

The part after the command "optional -gap_packages ..." is the clue.

How to actually install that package may depend on how you've installed Sage. Running `sage -i gap_packages` or `make gap_packages` from the top-level Sage directory should do it. But this is not a math question anymore (if it was at all), so please direct inquiries about installation to the sage-support Google group or to ask.sagemath.org.